# CDI @Named annotation dont work as expected

Tags: java, cdi

I annoted the class ParametroSistemaHelper in this way:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class ParametroSistemaHelper {

    @Inject
    private BasicDAO dao;
```

After this i'm trying to use this in another class:

```
public abstract class BasicCrudMBImpl {    

    @Inject
    private ParametroSistemaHelper parametroSistemaHelper;
```

But when i try to start server (tomcat) i got error:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ParametroSistemaHelper with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private br.com.jwebbuild.mb.BasicCrudMBImpl.parametroSistemaHelper
  at br.com.jwebbuild.mb.BasicCrudMBImpl.parametroSistemaHelper(BasicCrudMBImpl.java:0)
```

I noted that in start of server the following message apper:

```
Managed Bean [class br.com.cardoso.mb.DisciplinaMBImpl] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably `ParametroSystemaHelper` is annotated by 
`@javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped` instead of `@javax.enterprise.inject.ApplicationScoped`. CDI container scans application for CDI beans but can't find your bean because scope is not defined explicitly.
This is for CDI 1.1 when `beans.xml` contains `bean-discovery-mode="annotated"` or is omitted that also means `annotated` discovery mode.

Comment: I checked the import and it is not javax.faces

Comment: Are there errors in console regarding injection BasicDAO? Is it CDI bean?

Comment: BasicDAO is a interface and BasicDAOImpl is your implementation. WHen start sserver don't apper any error about BasicDAO. THe BasicDAOImpl have "@Named and @ApplicationScoped" annotations.